# Passing Object Parameter To Another Function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

The current code fails because element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow" is not referencing the object that I passed in as a parameter (mydiv).

How do I give func2 the reference to the element "mydiv"? I know this code does not require func2, as what can be done in func2 can be done in func1, but for my actual code I need to pass the object to another function.
How can I do this in JavaScript without jquery?
Thanks.

```
function func1() {
    var a = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    a.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    function func2(a);
}

function func2(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
}
```

Comment: Remove the word `function` on your `function` call... `function func2(a);`...it should be just `func2(a);`

Comment: Wow this was a horribly dumb question. sorry.

Comment: No problem @Y.Moondhra ..I'm glad to help, and everyone has this kind of mistakes and errors at the begining so, no problem, and keep going!

Comment: I added another line to the code: document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = element.style.left;     and now it actually doesnt work. I can change but not get the element's "left" component until AFTER i give it a value through javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `function` in order to call `func2`, `function` keyword only use when you need to define new `function`.

```
function func1() {
    var a = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    a.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    func2(a);
}

function func2(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this was a simple mistake that I kept looking over. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the word function from `function func2(a);`.

Your code should look like this.

```js
function func1() {
    var a = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    a.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    func2(a); //You just need to update this line.
}

function func2(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
}
```

Try to google for JavaScript Hoisting to get more details.